# Why does swapoff -a only work for a few hours?

Tags: swap, docker

I'm running a docker container on Ubuntu, and I disable swap using **swapoff -a** because swap causes performance issues.

Now it works great for some hours and then swap creeps back on again. Any idea why? and how can I keep it turned off?

Answer (score 0):

Please remember that by disabling swap You are putting Yourself at risk losing progress of anything You do in case of unexpected shutdown.

To disable swap edit `/etc/fstab`

`sudo nano /etc/fstab`

Then comment every line with `#` that is responding to **swap**.

Regarding `swapoff`, its only disabling swap for current session.